# Configure EMR to use s3a instead of s3 for spark.sql calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-iam

All my calls to spark.sql("") fails with the error in the stacktrace **(1)** below

**Update - 2**
I have zeroed in on the problem, it is AccessDenied for sts:AssumeRule, any leads appreciated

```
User: arn:aws:sts::00000000000:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_XXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY/i-3232131232131232 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::00000000000:role/EMR_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY
```

When the same location is accessed with

```
spark.read.parquet("s3a://xxx.xxx-xxx-xx.xxxxx-xxxxx/xxx/")
```

I was able to read the records.

But the same stacktrace **(1)** resurfaces when access with **s3:** instead of **s3a:** scheme

```
spark.read.parquet("s3://xxx.xxx-xxx-xx.xxxxx-xxxxx/xxx/")
```

So how can I configure Spark on EMR to use **s3a:** or have **s3:** running without the access denied which is presume because it may not be using the appropriate credential chain

**(1)**

```
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.AWSSecurityTokenServiceException: Access denied (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1658)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1322)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1072)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:745)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:719)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:701)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:669)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:651)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:515)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.doInvoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1369)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1338)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.invoke(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:1327)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.executeAssumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:488)
  at com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.assumeRole(AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient.java:460)
```

**Update - 1**
Tried setting secret and access key doesn't work

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", "")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", "")
```

Comment: s3a is specifically for hadoop. http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A

Comment: Is it the same error after you set the secret and access keys? Did you also set `"fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem"` and `"fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"` (s3 bucket region)? You may also want to check the bucket permissions and policy.

Comment: Yes same error, I will try setting up the endpoint and see

Answer (score 0):

this stack trace says "amazon EMR S3 client"; not the Apache ASF one, so different settings, and error messages.

That error message about "assumed role" hints that you are running in an EC2 VM (yes?), and that "assumed role" is actually the IAM role the EC2 VM is deployed as. In which case (a) no other credentials are being picked up and (b) that VM doesn't have permissions to access the role. Fixes: work out the setting to get the credentials in, increase EC2 IAM role rights, or create VMs with a different role