# sts:AssumeRole failing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to access a AWS Glue table from EMR running Spark, I get the below error in my CloudTrail

```
User: arn:aws:sts::00000000000:assumed-role/EMR_EC2_XXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY/i-3232131232131232 is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::00000000000:role/EMR_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY
```

**EMR_EC2_XXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY** is the role that has been given for the Instance profile of the EC2 instances in the cluster and **EMR_XXXXXX_XXXXXX_POLICY** is the role of the EMR clutser, 
both roles has **AWSS3FullAccess** and Policy for accessing the KMS key attached, additionally EC2 role has **ElasticMapReduceRoleforEc2** and EMR has **ElasticMapreduceRole** attached resp.

Comment: What did you configure for the Trust Relationships? This must be set to allow a service to assume a role.

Comment: @JohnHanley did that just now and got it to work, but will you be able to explain why is this required for EMR and EC2, I can access the same S3 location when accessed from Spark on EMR using s3a://, but when accessing using s3:// it fails

Comment: My question on that is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53883833/configure-emr-to-use-s3a-instead-of-s3-for-spark-sql-calls

Comment: To call StsAssumeRole() you need to grant permissions to allow this. This is a security feature to prevent a service from calling StsAssumeRole. The role that the AWS service is running under might have one set of permissions and the new role another more privileged set. The Trust Relationship specifies that this is permitted.

Comment: There are 2 default roles, EMR_DefaultRole and EMR_EC2_DefaultRole and they dont seem to have this trust relationship configured between them, I just created custom roles based on that with some additional policies, I wonder why this problem comes up with custom roles

Comment: The roles that you mentioned are assigned to EMR when the service is created. The difference is you are trying to create new permissions by calling StsAssumeRole from the role assigned to EMR. You must grant permission to call StsAssumeRole for the new role.

Comment: If your real goal to allow EMR to have more priviliges, assign those permissions to the role that EMR is launced under. You don't need to call StsAssumeRole.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185627/discussion-between-somasundaram-sekar-and-john-hanley).

Comment: If you need more information, create a more specific question. I do not like long chat sessions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach inline policy to source account role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::{Destination_Account}:role/to-be-assumed-role"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```